# How to make a single backslash string

Tags: python

I'd like to make a list which is literally this: `'\'`. But doing `string = '\'` raises an EOL SyntaxError. How would I do it?

Many answers say to do `string = '\\'` but then when I print the string it shows as `'\\'` not `'\'`

**EDIT 1** This used to be about a list containing a string (`['\']` rather than `'\'`). But I realised the list was not the issue. That's why some of the answers talk about a list.

**EDIT 2** This is a vscode notebook issue! **More edit** It doesn't happen in a standard Jupyter notebook. Even when I try to write `string = '\\'` to a file rather than just print it, it comes out as `'\\'`

Comment: Try `ls = ['\\']`

Comment: As @Ghoti said use two ```'\\'``` as a single backslash indicates an escape character, used in cases like ```'\n'``` or ```'\t'``` etc

Comment: This is nothing to do with lists. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Try to create just a string with a backslash in it, and see if you still get the same `SyntaxError`.

Comment: You can always use `chr(92)` to create a single `'\'`

Comment: @dawg nice. That or ditch vscode lol

Comment: @AlexanderSoare are you trying to use single backslash?

Comment: @Xitiz I have tried it. It gives the EOS error as my question states.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare That is not right thing to edit the question and manipulate the answer! I suggest you to add all of your previous edit and make our answer clear. It is like we answered you unnecessary things!

Comment: @AlexanderSoare at first you asked the question for `["\"]` some people answered this, now you changed it to `'\'`. And again you changed it to `'\\'`. This basically became 3 question. And additionally different people answered for different question, and now question is different and their answers is unnecessary mess!

Comment: I'm sorry @Xitiz - I just didn't know in advance. I think the answers are valuable anyway, because people might not have a vscode issue in the end.

Comment: @Xitiz I've added the edit information in the main post so it's clear.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the list one. Which was the first question and there are 3 answers for that! @AlexanderSoare

Comment: @Xitiz I did. Please see edit 1

Comment: I think you should write "I was searching for `['\\']` but....."

Comment: @Xitiz sorted. .

Comment: I can't find a question pointing at a reproducible problem here. Please read [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bypass Python string interpolation logic using `chr(chr_number)` In this case `92`:

```
>>> li=[chr(92)]
>>> li
['\\'] # that is a SINGLE character of '\'
```

Then use `*` to make it any length:

```
>>> s=chr(92)*3
>>> s
'\\\\\\'
>>> len(s)
3
```

And it works in `f` strings as you may want:

```
>>> f'{chr(92)}'
'\\'
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question in it's current edited form. Would have also accepted: "don't use vs code"

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to this problem is to use two backslashes: `\\`. This way, Python sees the first backslash and interprets the second one literally.

```
ls = ['\\']
```

**Edit :**
If you're asking for double backslash then :

```
ls = [r'\\']
```

It is called raw string.

**Edit on question :**
You should use this:

```
string=r'\\'
```

Comment: Yes, but then the string is literally a double backslash

Comment: When I print the list it is '\\'

Comment: @AlexanderSoare have you mentioned that in question?

Comment: when you print the list you will see ["\\"] but if you print the element you'll see it's a single \

Comment: @AlexanderSoare I have edited! And suggest you not to edit question!

Comment: Sorry for the edits @Xitiz see the latest one which is now marked as an edit. Mystery identified

Comment: Sorry, that actuall prints `'\\\\'`. vscode is weird

Comment: yes! I'm going to try write it to file to see if it's just vscode printing it weird. Okay... it even saves '\\' to the file

Comment: I have tested on VsCode it is working perfectly fine for me! @AlexanderSoare I don't think you wrote that `r`

Comment: @Xitiz I did write the r. My vscode changed the notebook style about 2 weeks ago and it's been giving me headaches since. It now has all the fancy python checks but not worth the bugs.

Comment: Not for some people, It should help everyone. I suggest you to reinstall vscode and try it. Or change ide

Comment: @Xitiz I won't be doing that. Like I said, everything went downhill ever since they updated the notebooks.

Comment: @MSH OP edited the question multiple time in that process, when you look that question it was like that but when I am answering that OP just want to get single backslash `'\'`. I suspect if you have downvoted for that!

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. I usually only downvote for bad attitude or dangerous code something plainly wrong. You answer is none of those.

Comment: Okay! I suspect some have looked the answer and found it is unnecessary and give downvote cuz OP is constantly editing the answer. So, I have asked @dawg

Answer (score 1):

You can use double backslashes. Imagine that second one negates it.

```
ls = ['\\']
```

Comment: Yes, but then the string is literally a double backslash

Comment: Interesting, i tested it and it works as intended, prints single backslash.
Edit: comment on the other answer is right. You are printing the list, not list[0]. That's the issue.

Comment: hmm I'm in a vscode ipython notebook... just realised it works in the command line interpreter

Comment: It's not even a jupyter thing. Just vscode lol

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't be naming your string as string. It is a reserved word.

Comment: True. Maybe I should start using foo bar and the other one for these

Comment: Sorry, turns out it is not a reserved word for Python. Still, i wouldn't make it a habit to name a variable as 'string'. I should have checked before commenting.

Comment: yeah neither would I. was rushing to make the post

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

```
the_list = ["\\"]
```

**Explanation:**

The character `\` is an escape character. I means the character after `\` is not considered as a meaningful character.

For example if you want to put a `"` in a string you can do it by:

```
string = "There is a \" in my text"
```

So you should escape `\` inside the string.